# is it possible to connect Maya Calendar to Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: calendar

is it possible to connect Maya Calendar to Microsoft Exchange ? I couldn't have the information if Exchange is supporting Caldav, or maybe there are workarounds ?

Answer (score 3):

Exchange generally allows you to publish a calendar feed in .ics format. This will give Maya read-only access to your calendar. Here are instructions on [publishing the feed in Outlook 2007](https://it.uoregon.edu/Exchange-Google-Sync). You can also publish the feed [from the Outlook web app](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sharing-your-calendar-in-Outlook-Web-App-7ecef8ae-139c-40d9-bae2-a23977ee58d5?CorrelationId=3f167aea-2090-4ff7-a90e-cb7eaadf8a0b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc375064921).

Unfortunately, read/write Exchange support on Linux is limited. You might have better luck using the Outlook Web app. In the Midori web browser, if you open the Outlook web app and click Menu --> Create Launcher, you'll get a standalone wrapper for the web app that you can run from the Elementary launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Davmail to access your Exchange account and transform the calendar access to CalDAV.

1. First, install Davmail from http://davmail.sourceforge.net/
2. Configure it by pointing it to your Exchange OWA URL (you will have to do it the first time you run the application. If you want to change something later you will have to do it by modifying the .davmail.properties and restarting the davmail daemon, since Elementary Loki lacks a system tray)
3. Add a new calendar to Maya by using an address in the form http://localhost:1080/users/mail@company.com/calendar
4. Be aware of this issue: [Maya shows the events the day after but the integration with Wingpanel works perfect](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/maya-shows-the-events-the-day-after-but-the-integration-with-wingpanel-works-per)