# Maya shows the events the day after but the integration with Wingpanel works perfect

Tags: calendar

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Introduce an OwnCloud account via CalDAV
2. Create some event (Reboot if you want)
3. Open Maya and go to this day. It'll show no event this day
4. Check out the day after. The event will appear.
5. Try opening the Wingpanel access and go to this day. The event is correctly shown (the number isn't bold, but the day is correct).

Comment: I can also confirm. I'm on Loki and using Nextcloud v10. Maybe comment to a related issue or open a new one on Launchpad? Like https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1443056

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm, OwnClound via CalDAV, event in the right panel for today not shown, but if you select the next day, event from day before are there. There is a 1 day shift